# my web application is corrupted how to create a new content database using same web application?

Tags: configuration

My web application is corrupted, how do I create a new content database using the same web application?

What can I do ? I need to use same web application but with a new content database, I don't care about old data at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Central administration -> Application Management-> Database -> Manage Content Database. Select the required web application and delete the content database associated with it. After that add a new content database and use `Mount-SPContentDatabase` command to attach newly created content database to it. Example:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase "MyDatabase" -DatabaseServer "MyServer" -WebApplication http://sitename
```

Comment: thank you Nadeem, plz tell also how i create new content datbase

Comment: To add a new content database click on Add a content database on the same page.